# How do you sign up for Azure in Australia?

Tags: azure

Stupid question you say ? Well, I know we have data centres here.  I went to the sign up page and Microsoft texted me a code, which I entered.  The site told me it was invalid.  I clicked the link for support, that page is broken ( go to the dashboard and click support, it's broken from there too ).  I called the number I was given, and was told they do no Azure support, so they put me on to a chat.  Having someone who can't speak clear English tell me a Tiny Url with a code on the end was fun.

I spent three hours in total talking to online and phone chat.  Everyone pinged me to someone else.  At this point, the story is that the phone help for Azure is closed for the day, or just not taking calls, and the sign up form won't work because I can't provide a credit card with a US billing address.  Now, I admit that most people I spoke to didn't seem to understand my question, but I repeated it often enough.  I also called their support line, it's always undermanned.  They gave me an email to use which I can't work out, wappeans@microsoft.com ? Certainly, I've emailed and got no reply.

Is there any way I can sign up for an Azure account ?

At the core, I am going to:

https://account.windowsazure.com/signup?offer=ms-azr-0044p&appId=102

[image: Sign up form]

As you can see, it's asking for a US credit card.  I see no option to change countries.  I've ordered from people like Best Buy, giving my address but TX and a TX ZIP, but that failed in this case.  The exact error message centres around having to provide a valid address.  I can't get that far without entering card details, which I don't want in my screenshot :)

Comment: This will very likely get deleted as off topic, but for now have a +1 for the amusement it raised

Comment: That's a shame - Microsoft literally refuse to help, the MS support forums have let me down, where am I supposed to turn?  If I wanted to play for laughs, this would be five paragraphs, I was really trying to ask a question about something that seems ridiculously difficult and should be easy.  I'll be signing up with AWS if I can't get signed up to Azure, soon.  I'm only holding out because I did all my research on if Azure would support all the things we need.

Comment: It is a very bizarre situation, I know that Aus Azure does have restrictions that the rest of them don't have, but I've never heard of anyone not being able to sign up. Could you create a Trial US account and raise a billing support call?

Comment: I can't create an account at all, without a US credit card.  That's where I am now stuck.  I don't know if the 'enter a code we text you' thing succeeded (it has disappeared, but when I entered what they texted me, they told me it was wrong).

Comment: @cgraus, let see if i can help (since my subscription was created with Australian address during my time in Aussie)

Can you describe a bit more details what what kind of subscription are you creating? will be good if you can provide any screenshot that with error on it.

Comment: Your only real options are going to be to continue trying to raise a response through Azure support. Finding the number of a local / Aus based MS / Azure office and calling directly. Contacting an Azure vendor so they can push it through their support channel (which will likely be more direct) or finally, there's always AWS ;)

Comment: Thanks Xiaomin - I have edited to show where I am able to get and explain what's going wrong

Comment: Thanks Michael - I'm assured by Microsoft that the 1-800 number I am calling, which appears to be in the USA, is the Australian support number.

Comment: @cgraus see my answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure billing question, requiring contact with billing support. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

@cgraus,

From your screenshot, i can see your first step is verification by card instead of "About you". My guess is you must have sign-up some other Microsoft service at some point that invoked billing, e.g xbox and choose U.S as region.

Once region is set, you are not able to change it. the only solution as I known is to create a new Microsoft account(new hotmail/outlook account). Then when you try to create an Azure subscription, you will see below screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually thinking about it, this does make sense, my original (first!) Azure account was an existing account and I had trouble getting it to work. I had to create a new account and everything went fine - well spotted. +1

Comment: Thank you.  I don't have an XBox, but it's possible that I activated a US MSDN with this account when I was an MVP.  The whole process was very user hostile and it's really disappointing I need an account tied to an email I don't read, but, at least I have a path forward, thank you.